# Trying to manage a large UITableView data structor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UINavigationController` which fetches items from a web service. I make calls to the web services - it checks if there are more items to load - if there are - I load a new instance of the same `viewController` with the new data from the web service. This works well.

What I also do is show a "Loading" screen which again, another instance of the same view controller with just one `UITableViewCell` that says loading. This gives a nice experience and no UI lock up while the Web service is busy.

When there are no more items to display (Can only know this once the web service has come back) I push a new view controller on the stack - lets call it `viewControllerB`.

So it works like this:

**When we have more items back from the Web service:**

`UITableViewCell` tapped - > `Web service call` starts - > new instance of current `viewControllerA` pushed onto the stack with the "Loading cell" - > `more items` from WebService - reload current instance of the `viewController` with more data.

**When we don't get items back from the Web service:**

`UITableViewCell` tapped - > `Web service call` starts - > new instance of current `viewControllerA` pushed onto the stack with the "Loading cell" - > `no more items` from WebService -push to `viewControllerB`

Now the problem is when I go back to `viewControlerA` from `viewControllerB` I get the "Loading more" screen and have to go back one more level to the last set of results in `viewControllerA`

How can I bypass the loading screen and just go to last results?

Lastly, is there another way to do this without loading new instances of the same view controller onto the stack? While keeping data from the previous screen?

Comment: Have you considered using separate section that will contain the only "Loading cell" ? Then you could simply call -reloadData method and decide when to show "Loading cell" based on number of responses from web server.

Comment: You can use singelton class and keep the data in one insatnce http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/. Can you be more specific about controllers or post some code. Maybe you can remove "Loading more" screen from viewWillAppear method of viewControlerA, you can even set some bool flag to check if your data is loaded and reload data of the table

Comment: @oradyvan - I haven't considered that. I like the idea. I will try it out now. user2432612 - I already have a singleton class for data. However this data is just text and nothing more. The reason I have loading more screen to to avoid the look of the app has frozen to the user if the web service takes long to come back with an answer (Slow connections, etc) So the question is how do I indicate that I am loading more data without a loading more screen? I will update the question with some code for clarification. Thank you.

Comment: @oradyvan I tried your suggestion. The problem is if I just reload the view with new data - I can't navigate back up to the top without calling the web service again. The way I am doing it now - each instance of the view controller stays in memory. So the data stays too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use async request to server, the operation will work in another thread, so your application will not freeze main thread. Here is a quick example:

```
-(void) myFuncToServerRequest{

    [self setLoading];

    NSMutableString *post = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"mykey="];
    [post appendString:@"myValue"];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSString *urlApi = @"yoursite.com";

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
        [self unselectLoading];
        if (error){

        }
        else{
        // return to main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   // Do what you want with your data
                });


        }
    }];
}
```

My key and my value are parametars of request you can append post variable with more key and values strings.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem isn't the loading of the data. That happens in the background anyway - its what to show the user while that is happening. If I don't show anything it will look like the app is not responding.

Comment: @Tander You can use some custom cell as loader. Just add some flag that you are loading data, and inside your numberOfRowsInSection check if is loading data and return one, and in cellForRow.. return your loader cell. Make sure you reload data when you start and finish. Or you can even add a view `[self.view addSubview:loaderView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:loaderView];`
and make sure you enable disable scrolling 
`[self.tableView setScrollEnabled:false];`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've got something like that. Problem is from view controllerB (Details page) back to viewControllerB I get the loading cell on screen - because there is no data. I need to go up one more level to get stored data in memory. I am thinking of piping that view controller off the stack by code. But its prone to issues.

Comment: You can store your data variable to Singelton class and access it from any view controller. Or did i miss something? :)